Unable to determine the device handle for GPU0000:01:00.0: Unknown Error
I got after sometimes
Unable to determine the device handle for GPU0000:01:00.0: Unknown Error

when i check nvidia-smi
ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS , nvidia-driver : 535.183.06
every time i got this problem i reboot the laptop and fixed but after  sometimes of working on GPU i got this again
I searched a lot but couldn't find what is the problem ?
